# Why is the run-time efficiency for this code O(n^2)?

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, runtime, big-o

Sorry, I am new at big O analysis. I need some help with this:

I have the following code segment:

```
int sum; 
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  
     if (n < 1000)    
         sum++; 
     else    
         sum += foo(n); 
}
```

the solution key says that this is O(n^2) analysis, but I can't understand why. The loop only interates once, so where does n^2 come from?

Another one I'm having trouble with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n + 100; ++i) { 
   for (int j = 0; j < i * n ; ++j)
     sum = sum + j; 
} 

for (int k = 0; k < n + n + n; ++k){ 
   c[k] = c[k] + sum; 
}
```

These come out to be O(n^3), but I'm also not sure how this happens. I know that there are 3 loops, but they aren't nested, so where does n^3 come from?

Comment: The overall time complexity of the first snippet depends on the time complexity of `foo()`.

Comment: well, what does `foo()` do? can't fully analyze the entire loop without knowing what each component's big-O is. I can't see why the 3rd loop would be O(n^3). It's O(3n) at best, which is really just O(n).

Comment: "I know that there are 3 loops, but they aren't nested, so where does n^3 come from" - that's not how complexity analysis works. you cannot simply "count" the loops.

Comment: @MarcB: check the second one again.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: yes, **IF** the O(n^3) applies to all three loops considered as a single unit. OP isn't particularly clear if the loops are being analyzed together, or separately.

Comment: @MarcB since they are formatted as a single code block I think it is safe to assume they are one code fragment.

Answer (score 3):

1) This might have to do with the implementation of `foo()`. If `foo()` is `O(n)`, this method will be `O(n^2)`

2) The inner loop goes to `i*n`, where `i` also goes to `n`, thus is quadratic in `n` making the two loops `O(n^3)` in total. The third loop is only `O(n)` so can be ignored in the analysis.